# Inserted value too large for column: "oracle.sql.STRUCT@c85ad79"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

JSON Request :

```
{
"telephoneAddress" : {
    "phoneType" : "RESADD",
    "countryCode" : "87654321",
    "areaCode" : "0111",
    "telephoneNumber" : "8097739267",
    "extensionNum" : "9111",
    "formatCode" : "as",
    "unlistTelephoneNumInd" : "y"
}
}
```

Procedure call from java code :

```
 rspParmMap = this.applicationsProcPut.withProcedureName("MS_PUT_CTC_DETAILS")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("V_MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ",
                oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.STRUCT)).execute(reqParamMap);
```

Can anybody let me know why I am getting this error and what is use of `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.STRUCT` ?

Let me know if you want to more information regarding this error.

Size of column in sequence of JSON data being inserted top to bottom :

```
VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

Sqlobj in java

```
    private long appReferNum;

    private int ipIdNum;
    private String seqNo;
    private String postalTableInd;
    private String emailTableInd;
    private String teleTableInd;
    private TelephoneAddObj telephoneAddObj;
    private PostalAddObj postalAddObj;
    private EmailAddObj emailAddObj;

        //get,set
    @Override
        public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
            return "MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ"; // sqltype name in oracle
        }
```

sql type

```
create or replace 
            TYPE "MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ" 
                AS 
        OBJECT(
    v_app_refer_num      NUMBER,
    v_ip_id_num          NUMBER,
    v_seqNo             VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_postalTableInd    VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_emailTableInd     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_teleTableInd     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),

    v_TELE_ADD_DEL IP_TELE_ADDR_OBJ,
    v_POST_ADD_DEL IP_POSTAL_ADD_OBJ,
    v_EMAIL_ADD_DEL IP_EMAIL_ADD_OBJ );
```

procedure

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE 
MS_PUT_CTC_DETAILS(
  V_MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ IN MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ,
  v_status OUT varchar2
  --,v_postal_status OUT varchar2
 -- ,v_email_status OUT varchar2
) AS .
```

.
.
.
.just updating the things

Comment: Did you checked your column length ? looks like you are inserting larger value than a column can handle.

Comment: We can't see your procedure definition to see how its formal argument is declared - presumably it's expecting an object type, hence the struct - but more importantly can't see what the procedure is doing, which table(s) it's modifying, the column data types of those, or what data it's trying to put in them. What does the JSON have to do with it?

Comment: @SantanuSahoo I was expecting this question I have already checked column length is more than I am inserting

Comment: @kiranrathod if you are sure that a question will be asked, it's better to clarify in the posted question itself.

Comment: @AlexPoole m trying to update data in db the thing is call from above java code to procedure in not happening

Comment: @kiranrathod - but you haven't given us any information to help you understand why that might be happening. What is the procedure definition? How is the Oracle object type declared? What Java object are you mapping to that, and what are its attribute datatypes and values? If everything looks superficially right, do you have multibyte characters or a character set mismatch, perhaps?

Comment: So... are we to assume that you are parsing that JSON into a Java object - and you haven't shown us the object or the parsing code - and then passing that Java object (as a struct) to a procedure which is expecting an Oracle object with those field sizes? I'm not sure what you think we can do with so little info.

Comment: @AlexPoole question updated

Answer (score 0):

Structs and Array are the advance datatype,  from the [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html).

> The Oracle database and the PL/SQL language used for stored procedures
>   in Oracle has built in support for some advanced data types. These
>   data types can't easily be accessed using standard JDBC APIs, so it is
>   necessary to rely on Oracle's JDBC extensions like ARRAY and STRUCT
>   and the APIs that are used to access them.

Please check your **STRUCT**/ **Table** columns length. also be aware of any special character which may take more than 1 length.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for above question :

In your sql type java object where you overriding writeSQL() method :

```
  @Override
public void writeSQL(final SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
                stream.writeLong(this.appReferNum);
                stream.writeInt(this.ipIdNum);
                stream.writeString(this.seqNo);
                stream.writeString(this.postalTableInd);
                stream.writeString(this.emailTableInd);
                stream.writeString(this.teleTableInd);
                stream.writeObject(this.getTelephoneAddObj());
                stream.writeObject(this.getPostalAddObj());
                stream.writeObject(this.getEmailAddObj());

            }
```

you need to follow the sequence same as your sqltype as below and do not skip any property in writeSQL() method of sql java object

```
create or replace 
            TYPE "MS_CTC_DTL_OBJ" 
                AS 
        OBJECT(
    v_app_refer_num      NUMBER,
    v_ip_id_num          NUMBER,
    v_seqNo             VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_postalTableInd    VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_emailTableInd     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
    v_teleTableInd     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),

    v_TELE_ADD_DEL IP_TELE_ADDR_OBJ,
    v_POST_ADD_DEL IP_POSTAL_ADD_OBJ,
    v_EMAIL_ADD_DEL IP_EMAIL_ADD_OBJ );
```